# how to render view from object using backbonejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

template code :

```
<script type="text/template" id="baseTemplate">
        <% collection.each(function() { %>
            <div>
                <%= collection %>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
</script>
<div id="baseContainer"></div>
```

and other code is :

```
//model
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "id":null,
        "title":"",
        "content":""
    },
});
//collection
var PageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: PageModel
    },
    model: PageModel,
    url: 'api/get_page/?id=6'
});
//view
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#baseContainer'),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new PageCollection();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function () {

    var html = _.template($("#baseTemplate").html(), { collection: this.collection });
    this.$el.html(html);
    console.log(html);
    return this;
    }
});

 var page = new PageView();
```

problem is that its return and object how can i get values from object? api link is `http://furqankhanzada.com/backbonejs/api/get_page/?id=6` and here you can see object in browser console `http://furqankhanzada.com/backbonejs/`
i need to get title, content , attachments -> images -> Gallery Large -> url (attachments using each() ).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how can i get values from object?". Do you mean inside your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this is proper solution or not, but you can give it a try.

An alternative can be like,

```
var html = _.template($("#baseTemplate").html(), { models: this.collection.models });
```

Pass models instead of directly passing collection. And in the template you can do something like this,

```
<script type="text/template" id="baseTemplate">
  <% _.each(models, function(mdl) { %>
    <div>
      <%= mdl.get('title') %>
      <%= mdl.get('content') %>
      <% _.each(mdl.get('page').attachments, function(attachment) { %>
        <%= attachment.images["Gallery Large"].url %>
     <% }) %>  
   </div>
  <% }); %>
</script>
<div id="baseContainer"></div>
```

Please modify the markup as per your needs. But this solution is too specific to the problem :( :(

Comment: What error is it giving ?
And can you please check that value does `this.collection.models` have in the view ?

Comment: Now it looks like the [url](http://furqankhanzada.com/backbonejs/) is giving proper collection object. Can you please replace `mdl.title` with `mld.get('title')`, `mdl.content` with `mdl.get('content')` and `mdl.page.attachments` with `mdl.get('page').attachments` in the template and give it a try ?

Comment: mdl.get('page') has hole page and we just need to add attr name like mdl.get('page').title, mdl.get('page').content, mdl.get('page').attachment.
its mean we don't need collections ?

Comment: you think this is Good Solution ?

Comment: Yes Furqan, thats what I thought of writing in answer when I wrote it, saying that if every time  collection is going to have only one model, then we should not be using collection, coz it defeats the purpose of collection. Instead just a model can be created and used.

Comment: for example i clicked page1, then page2. do you think collection have still page 1 data. ? and model can do this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19015/discussion-between-cyclone-and-furqan)